# Prove $\forall\epsilon>0:\exists m\in\mathbb{N}:\forall n\ge m:b_n-a_n<\epsilon$ for nested intervals

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How do I prove that $\forall\epsilon>0:\exists m\in\mathbb{N}:\forall n\ge m:b_n-a_n<\epsilon$ for the following nested intervals:

$$\begin{array}{ll}a_1=1&;&b_1&=x\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(x>1)\\
a_{n+1}=\frac{2a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n}&;&b_{n+1}&=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}\end{array}$$

with $(I_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}:=[a_n,b_n]$.

I thought about induction, however, I can't even solve the base case. How do you tackle such proofs?

Comment: you wrote $b_n=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}$. Is this correct or should it be $b_{n+1}$?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo No, it was incorrect. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is not too hard to see that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are always positive and $a_n<b_n$.  Therefore $b_n-a_n<b_n+a_n$ and so
$$\eqalign{b_{n+1}-a_{n+1}
  &=\frac{a_n+b_n}2-\frac{2a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n}\cr
  &=\frac{(b_n-a_n)^2}{2(a_n+b_n)}\cr
  &<\frac{b_n-a_n}2\ .\cr}$$
That is, the difference $b_n-a_n$ is (at least) halved at each step.  By induction we have
$$b_m-a_m<\frac{x-1}{2^{m-1}}$$
for all $m$.  Given $\epsilon$, you need to find $m$, which may be in terms of $\epsilon$ and $x$, such that
$$\frac{x-1}{2^{m-1}}<\epsilon\ .$$
See if you can fill in the details of the induction which I omitted, and then finish things from here.

Comment: isn't that enough to show since it gets smaller and smaller?

Comment: It's enough in terms of ideas, but I think you still ought to write things up very carefully in terms of $\epsilon,n$ and $m$ as in the question.  Also, "smaller and smaller" is not the same as "approaches zero", for example $\frac32,\frac43,\frac54,\frac65,\ldots$

Comment: I really have a problem with doing so. I have no clue at all how to find/define $m$.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I got it now!

Answer (score 0):

We have $a_n<b_n$ by the harmonic-arithmetic mean inequality.

Therefore $a_n<a_{n+1}$. It follows $b_{n+1}-a_{n+1} < \frac{a_n+b_n}{2}-a_n=\frac{b_n-a_n}{2}$. The proof follows.